# Strategies for distributing SQL-server-based application

Tags: sql-server

I have written an application in vb.net, based on SSCE.  Now I need to shift in SQL Server Express because I need to run the application on Sharing (LAN) and several users need to access the database at the same time.
I am absolutely new to SQL Server.  I need to know the following:

1) Do I create SQL Server DB by Adding New Item in my VS 2008? or they need to be created in SQL Server mgmt Express ONLY?

2) How do I distribute these database, same way like SSCE databses?

3) Can these databases be used like we use Access DBs in sharing (just put in the shared folder)?

4) If no to Question 3, how to set the connection string as I donot know the name of computer of the user who will install my application.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. To create a new database, the easiest thing would probably be to do
   into SQL Server Management studio, open the instance of SQL Server
   where the database will live, right click on the "Databases" folder
   and select "New Database...".  Once the database is there you can add tables and the like.
2. You will not distribute this database.  Instead you will include a
   connection string in your application that references this DB.  All
   data will live on a single instance.
3. No, you will not share this like you shared an Access Database.  One
   problem I have with Access is that the untrained masses are set
   loose on the database to do as they please.  I would give as few
   people as possible access to the database.  And when you give them access limit their permissions to the bare minimum they need.  If you want someone to
   change the data in there create an application that allows them to
   modify table records as **you** see fit.
4. Take a look at [this link](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008) for an explanation of how you should setup
   your connection string.  The connection string itself will not vary
   between machines.  You will just need to use the appropriate account
   that has the appropriate access to the DB.  You will also need to
   make sure that the server where the DB is running is accessible.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks !

I made an instance of SQL Server Express and connect it with a basic report.  On the development server, it works ok. 

Then I shared the folder and then ran the application from some other network computer (LAN)

It gave error that it could not find the server.  Could you advise what could be the problem.



Thanks

Comment: Sounds like the computer you ran the app from cannot access the server.  You will probably need to look at how your permissions are setup.